# Building single files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, latex, build

I'm moving to Eclipse for Python (with PyDev) and LaTeX (with TeXlipse) but I couldn't find how to build a single file.

This is not so much of a problem for python, because I usually create projects, but isn't there a simple way to build a latex document with Eclipse? I find it a bit cumbersome to always have to create a project, then go through Import->File System->Choose the file to actually be able to edit and compile it.

Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try File -> Open File to open an arbitrary file without first creating a project.

Comment: But then I can't build it. For example I can open an arbitrary latex document, but not compile it.

Comment: The build and other IDE features are only available within projects.

Comment: How come eclipse does this? All other ides have a build button for single files, at least for latex.

Comment: I am not familiar with how other IDEs handle single file build outside the context of a project. Maybe its not an issue for latex, but in general, building is not possible without extra metadata describing environment, dependencies, output directories, technologies, etc. None of this metadata is present when opening an arbitrary file. If you feel that this shouldn't preclude single file build for latext, I suggest you contact the people providing the latex plugin to expose such build-like action from that plugin. This action may have to open a dialog to ask you for output location, etc.

Comment: In C, building a single file makes sense; so does it in C#, or in VB.net, or in python, or Java, and so on. Only for complex projects is it required to have the metadata in question. Sad that eclipse cannot do what Code::Blocks can.

Comment: You can only build a single file in all those languages that you've referenced for the most trivial cases. So much so that it isn't worth it to implement work flow for that in Eclipse. Latex may be different. The bottom line is if you got a tool that does what you need, used it. If you want to see latex support in Eclipse improved, see my prior comment.